# How to check the displayed date in Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, date, dateformatter

I am trying to get the displayed date in the exact format to validate if it is in MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm. I tried :

```
element.getAttribute("value")
```

but that returns "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm" which actually is different than what is in UI.

Also when I use:

```
LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
String date = dtf.format(currentDateTime);
```

works fine: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz97a.png)

Answer (score 1):

The data from the UI may have been converted into [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) by the **bootstrap** library. Therefore, if you need to get the value in the *MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm* format, you can do so using a `DateTimeFormatter`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "2021-06-01T04:05";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = LocalDateTime.parse(input).format(formatter);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
06/01/2021 04:05
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/LTD0M1)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>